# code has error: unable to get the vlookup property of the worksheetfunction class

Tags: vba, excel

I had an issue with this code before and when I tried fixing it another issue occurred. On this line of code,

```
If Not (IsError(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(item, lookup_range, 2, False))) Then
```

I get the error unable to get the vlookup property of the worksheetfunction class"

The whole code is below. Thanks for any help!

```
Sub code()
Columns("E:G").Insert shift:=xlToRight, copyorigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("E6").value = "Drink Price"
Range("F6").value = "Drink Revenue"
Range("G6").value = "Gross Sales less Drink Revenue"
Dim i As Variant
Dim item As Variant
Dim lookup_range As Range
Dim rev_wksht As Worksheet
Dim rev_wbk As Workbook
Dim vlkup_wbk As Workbook
Set rev_wksht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Set vlkup_wbk = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\user\Documents\vlookup table drink prices.xlsx")
Set lookup_range = vlkup_wbk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:B")
i = 7
Do While rev_wksht.Cells(i, 1).value <> ""
   Set item = rev_wbk.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).value
    If Not (IsError(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(item, lookup_range, 2, False))) Then
        rev_wksht.Cells(i, 5).value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(item, lookup_range, 2, False)
        rev_wksht.Cells(i, 6).Formula = rev_wksht.Cells(i, 11).value * rev_wksht.Cells(i, 5).value
        rev_wksht.Cells(i, 7).Formula = rev_wksht.Cells(i, 4).value - rev_wksht.Cells(i, 6).value
    ElseIf (IsError(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(item, lookup_range, 2, False))) Then
        rev_wksht.Cells(i, 5).value = Empty
    End If
i = i + 1
Loop
rev_wksht.Range("F:G").NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
rev_wksht.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Comment: try application.vlookup

Comment: Thank you Phil, that worked! If your don't mind answering but what's the difference between  Application.VLookup and Application.worksheet. VLookup? Why does vlookup work when the worksheet part isn't there?

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that you have not set rev_wbk.

Comment: ++ You beat me to it :D

Comment: ohh I didn't even notice that. Thank you! but another issue is that this line, "If Not (IsError(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(item, lookup_range, 2, False))) Then " now says unable to get the vlookup property of the worksheetfunction class.

Answer (score 2):

You have declared `Dim rev_wbk As Workbook` but you have not initialized it and hence you are getting the error

Answer (score 1):

> I get the error "Run time error 91, object variable or with block variable not set" but I have set when I assign item's value. I tried with and without set...

`Set` keyword is used to assign *to* an object-type only. `item` is `Variant` and while it could be an object, a `Range.Value` is not an object type, it's a string, numeric, or error type and would be assigned like:

```
item = ...
```

The actual Runtime 91 error means you're referencing an object variable which hasn't yet been assigned an instance of an object. Look over your code: you don't ever `Set rev_wbk ...` to any existing `Workbook` so while you've declared it as a `Workbook` object, it's presently a `Nothing`, and you can't do `Nothing.Method` or `Nothing.Property` without raising the 91 error :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Application.Vlookup

I'm not 100% sure why application.worksheetfunction.vlookup stopped working, but it used to be distinct from application.vlookup because it returned different error objects if an error occurred.

At some point since office 2007, it appears to have been removed but the intellisense has stayed there.